# Why am I getting 401 error for a Rails jQuery POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise in a rails application. I can login to my rails server (devise) with this curl command:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"mrezaurrahman@sample.com\",\"password\":\"3213421\"}}"
```

Output is like:

```
 {"success":true,"info":"Logged in :) ","data":{"authentication_token":"8JySqFVx_pKx_3nx67AJ"}}
```

Now I need to access my server with javascript. This is my jquery code:

```
var invitation_creation = {
                      "email": "mrezaurrahman@sample.com",
                      "password": "3213421"
                    }

              $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions.json",
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"))},  
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: JSON.stringify(invitation_creation),
                        success: function(){ console.log("success")}

                    });
```

But now I'm getting following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I already have a user who has email "mrezaurrahman@sample.com" and password "3213421".
I can log in using curl, but I can't use my javascript code.

How can I log in to this system using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try to use this:

```
var invitation_creation = { "user": {
                      "email": "mrezaurrahman@sample.com",
                      "password": "3213421"
                    }}
```

instead of

```
var invitation_creation = {
                      "email": "mrezaurrahman@sample.com",
                      "password": "3213421"
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped, I needed to reformat it a bit in order to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I had problem with JSON creation. The invitation_creation JSON declaration line would be like,

```
var invitation_creation =  {"user":{"email":"mrezaurrahman@live.com","password":"28902890"}};
```